# Is there a way to programmatically receive target uri for NiFi remote process group?

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-minifi

I'm trying to programmatically create a NiFi flow using the NiFi api.
I'm creating a remote process group in an inner flow.

The RPG request payload requires the target uri of the remote process group. Is there a way to get that uri programmatically via the api?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

NiFi Rest API docs are [here](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html):

Specifically, a `GET` on `/remote-process-groups/{id}` returns a *RemoteProcessGroupEntity* which contains the RPG info including URI.

```json
{
    "revision": {…},
    "id": "value",
    "uri": "value",
    "position": {…},
    "permissions": {…},
    "bulletins": [{…}],
    "disconnectedNodeAcknowledged": true,
    "component": {…},
    "status": {…},
    "inputPortCount": 0,
    "outputPortCount": 0,
    "operatePermissions": {…}
}
```

If you are using Python, consider [NiPyAPI](https://pypi.org/project/nipyapi/) for programmatically interacting with the NiFi API.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I think I didn't explain myself correctly - when creating the RPG's payload I need to include the target uri.  I need to somehow get that uri in order to create the RPG (and not in the connection payload as I mistakenly wrote)